# Set WO's asset via the Maximo map identify dialog

Tags: maximo

Version: Maximo 7.6.1.1/Spatial 7.6.0.5

Application: Work Order Tracking

---

In the map tab of a work order, I want to identify on an asset and click a button in the dialog to `set as WO's asset`.

[image]

---

Is it possible to do this in a button in the map identify dialog?

*(I would also want to do this for Locations too.)*

<sup>*Keyword: Maximo Spatial*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do what is needed but requires a good knowledge of different technologies. As you know, the Spatial map is composed of widgets written in Javascript that communicate with the ESRI server and with Maximo.
Therefore a possible approach could be:

1. add the new button to the widget (modify js code or extend it)
2. code the click event to send a message with the assetnum to a specific method of the WOTrack app-bean
3. this method must be able to receive the message, decode it and then set the asset in the current workorder.

PS:
If you don't want to use Java for backend logic, you can probably use an action script.

Comment: From a colleague: "There might be a way without customization using the MapTips feature.   In map manager in map tips tab, you can define menu items that will show up if you click in the maptips button from the identify dialog.   you can define a dialog that will be called. The main mbo of that dialog will be that asset from the map.  Then you could plug some automation scripts to this dialog, on a button maybe, to set that asset in the current app record. I never tried that and not sure if this still works right in Maximo, but used to work well in 7.5."

Comment: [Configuring map tips](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSG2D3_7.6.0/com.ibm.spl.doc/maps/t_ctr_config_maptips.html)

Comment: Good advice, thanks. If anyone tries it successfully let us know.